# SP2013 - create a new page under a subfolder, once save browse jump back to root folder

Tags: user-experience

We are migrating the sites from SP2010 to SP2013 and we found following behaviour changed. Anyway we can solve it?

In SP2010 - User open a document library and then open a subfolder. In the subfolder he click "Documents" at ribbon bar -> "New Document" -> New Page. After he type in the page name and other attributes, he click "create". The new page is saved and the browser return to the **subfolder** directory.

In SP2013 - User open document library and then open a subfolder. After he create the new page as mentioned abvove and click "create", the browser return to the **root** directory.

It is quite frustrate since he cannot see the new created file nor the directory. Anyway we can change the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Content Query WebPart after editing the page

```
<script src="../../../SiteAssets/ADJD/Scripts/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var cls=$('.ms-list-addnew > a'),
    attributes = {};

$.each(cls.get(0).attributes, function(i, attrib){
    attributes[attrib.name] = attrib.value;

});
var url=attributes.onclick.replace('Upload','CreatePage');
//var htm='</br><td class="ms-list-addnew ms-textXLarge ms-list-addnew-aligntop ms-soften"><a id="'+attributes.id+'" class="'+attributes.class+'" href="'+attributes.href+'" data-viewctr="custom" onclick="'+url+'" target="_self" title="Add a new page to this list or library."><span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20" style="font-size:20px""><img id="idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ2-img" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" class="ms-list-addnew-img20"></span><span style="font-size:20px">create page</span></a></td>'
//$('.ms-list-addnew > a').parent().parent().append(htm);
$('.ms-list-addnew > a').attr('onclick',url);

});
</script>
```